# Manipulating duplicate rows by merging similar colmns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have row 1 and 2 which they are similar in records except status column.

```
   +-----+------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
| #id | NAME | STATUS|   c_lan   | Java_lan | Dot_lan |
+-----+------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
|   1 |  A   |   111 |      yes  |    Q     | W       |
|   1 |  A   |   222 |      yes  |    Q     | W       |
|   2 |  B   |   333 |  NA       |    B     | C        |
+-----+------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

Now is it possible to have these tow rows (1,2) become as one row as like  below (need to merge status values in to one cell)?

```
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
| #id | NAME | STATUS    |   c_lan   | Java_lan | Dot_lan |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
|   1 | A    |   111,222 |      yes  |    Q     | W       |
|   2 | B    |   333     |  NA       |    B     | C       |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

noting that i am considering this to be done on mysql view

Comment: select id,name,group_concat(status) from table_name group by id

Comment: Are the rows always identical except for the STATUS column?

Comment: @jussius  ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"  as like the other RDBMS and throw an error when the GROUP BY is missing

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id,group_concat(distinct name),group_concat(distinct status),group_concat(distinct c_lan),group_concat(distinct java_lan),group_concat(distinct dot_lan)
FROM table1
GROUP BY id;